# Low Kappa score but high accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a dataset with 600 examples of target class yes and 300 of no.
After classification I get high accuracy(75%) but low kappa (0.4).
What can it mean? It seems that kappa is really low, am I right?
Other metrics like precission or AUR are about 0.7-0.8 what seems to be good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that anything is wrong here. With a binary target, chance is 50%, and 75% is half way to perfect accuracy of 100%.  Kappa, which ranges from 0 at chance to 1 at perfect separation, is 0.4, which is again a little less than half way to perfect prediction.  So it seems to be corroborating the performance of your model.

Kappa is defined as:
(observed accuracy - expected accuracy)/(1 - expected accuracy)

Since your classes appear balanced, you have (0.75 - 0.5) / (1 - 0.5) = 0.5

Comment: So is it correct score for the dataset? How big should be the accuracy then to get 0.6-0.8 kappa?

Comment: And class is not so balanced becuase 2/3 is Yes, 1/3 is No